# window.open() innerHTML is erased on Firefox... Sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, window.open

I'm working on a project that has a .NET app serving a dynamically generated webpage within the user's LAN. It populates the `tbody` of a table based on a user selection. What I'd like to do is allow the user to click on any row and have a small window popup with options specific to that row. It actually works find on Chrome, but on Firefox I get a blank window. When I recorded the screen it turns out that the window *does* populate correctly but then erases somehow.

I used developer tools on Firefox to step through the javascript, and found that when I set a breakpoint and continue, there's no issue - the window populates correctly. But when there is no breakpoint, the window ends up blank.

Here is the table HTML with sample test data in `tbody`. `tbody` has `id="OrderTableBody"`

```html
    <table id="pickList">
        <thead>
            <tr><td colspan=8 align=right><input type="checkbox" id="chk_HideLots" checked> Hide Fully Picked Lots</tr>
            <tr><th>Item Image<th>Cond.<th>Current Location<th>Color<th>Item Description<th>Qty Req'd<th>Qty Avail<th>Qty Picked</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="OrderTableBody">
            <tr><td><img src="https://img.bricklink.com/P/88/37543pb01.jpg" />
                <td>U
                <td>Box 01 - Minifigs & Plants
                <td>Reddish Brown
                <td>37543pb01: Eagle with Yellow Beak, White Head and Tail Feathers Pattern
                <td>1
                <td>0
                <td>1</tr>
            <tr><td><img src="https://img.bricklink.com/P/77/19303.jpg" /><td>Y<td>Z - Yellowed Parts (Pink Bin)<td>Pearl Dark Gray<td>19303: Minifigure, Headgear Helmet Mask<td>1<td>0<td>1</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is the javascript code that handles `onclick`:

```js
         document.querySelector('#OrderTableBody').onclick = function (e) {
            let popup = window.open("about:blank", '', 'width = 600, height = 200');
            let row = e.target.parentNode;
            if (row.tagName == "TD") { row = row.parentNode; }
            let optionStg = '<option value="0"> </option>';
            for (var i = 1; i <= Math.min(row.cells[6].innerHTML, row.cells[5].innerHTML - row.cells[7].innerHTML); i++) {
                optionStg += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
            }
            popup.document.body.innerHTML = '<table border=1><tr><td rowspan=4>' + row.cells[0].innerHTML +
                '<td>Cond: ' + row.cells[1].innerHTML + '<td>Ordered: <td>' + row.cells[5].innerHTML +
                '<td rowspan=4 valign="middle">PICK:<br><select id="qtyBox">' + optionStg + '</select></tr>' +
                '<tr><td>Color: ' + row.cells[3].innerHTML + '<td>Available: <td>' + row.cells[6].innerHTML + '</tr>' +
                '<tr><td>Item: ' + row.cells[4].innerHTML + '<td>Picked: <td>' + row.cells[7].innerHTML + '</tr>' +
                '<tr><td colspan=2>Location: ' + row.cells[2].innerHTML + '<//tr><//table><br><br>' +
                '<center><button type="button" id="pickButton">PICK TO ORDER</button>';
        }
```

So it's a weird thing - I'm getting window.open to work, but on Firefox is erases the content but not when I'm stepping through the js line by line. What might be causing this?

(BTW - I'm using `[Object].onclick` because `[Object].addEventListener('click', function (e) {` apparently does not provide me with permission to execute `window.open` on firefox, although that works fine on Chrome as well.)

Comment: Note that `<html>` does not belong inside body of the document

Comment: noted thanks. That used to be popup.innerHTML but I recently changed it to popup.document.body.innerHTML

Comment: Unrelated (?): If someone clicks an image, doesn't `e.target.parentNode;` return a `td`, not a row?

Comment: @wazz yes - I've added if (row.tagName == "TD") { row = row.parentNode; }. I'll update the code in the question for both comments